# How can I get {{.GitInfo}} in HUGO?

Tags: hugo

I want to update the '`Lastmod`' parameter for each page using the last git commit date for that content file. So I need set `"enableGitInfo = true"` firstly, however, when I coded `'{{.GitInfo}}'` in my html, I got a `'<nil>'`, and `{{.Lastmod}}` printed `'0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC'`.

I have written in `config.toml` as follows:

```
enableGitInfo = true

[frontmatter]
date = ["date","lastmod"]
lastmod = [":git", "lastmod", "date"]
publishDate = ["publishDate", "date"]
expiryDate = ["expiryDate"]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I successfully created a sample site to test this. See if any of these steps help you.

1. `hugo new site git-info-test`
2. `cd git-info-test`
3. Add `enableGitInfo = true` to the `config.toml` file
4. Create `layouts/index.html` and add `{{.GitInfo | jsonify}}`
5. `hugo new _index.md`
6. `git init`
7. `git add .`
8. `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
9. `hugo -D`
10. You should see something like this in the generated `public/index.html`

```
{
  "hash": "adf0bd47f37f413bf7c790a4c19c129cba6acf23",
  "abbreviatedHash": "adf0bd4",
  "subject": "Initial commit",
  "authorName": "John Smith",
  "authorEmail": "john.smith@email.com",
  "authorDate": "2019-07-22T14:59:20-05:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might seem obvious in hindsight, but what tripped me up is that you need a commit with that file before the `{{ .GitInfo }}` will show up.

It is pulling the data associated with the file, so if you move a file, or create one for the first time, you'll need a commit for this to populate.

This is assuming you have the requirements from [Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/variables/git/):

- The Hugo site must be in a Git-enabled directory.
- The Git executable must be installed and in your system PATH.
- The .GitInfo feature must be enabled in your Hugo project by passing --enableGitInfo flag on the command line or by setting `enableGitInfo` to true in your site’s configuration file (`config.toml`).

You might want to build some backup functionality in your template so that when previewing your Hugo site for pages not yet committed, you still see a date:

```html
{{ $date := now }}
{{ if .GitInfo }}
  {{ $date = .GitInfo.AuthorDate }}
{{ end }}

<div class="date">
  {{- $date.Format "January 02, 2006" -}}
</div>
```